# Expect Script - Auto Password

Tags: linux, send, expect, ssh-keys, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to make a script which automatically enters the password "root" to copy the ssh-key from A to B. Since ssh-copy does not work on B and also cant be installed i used:

```
ssh root@$ip mkdir -p .ssh
cat "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "root@$ip" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

To transfer the key. But B delets its storage on reboot. So i have to automate this process. I thought a expect script would be the simplest solution? I am however not very experienced with these.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#31.09.2015

set timeout 30

spawn ssh "root@$ip mkdir -p .ssh"
expect "password:"
send "root\r"
expect "(yes/no)? "
send "yes\r"

spawn cat "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "root@$ip" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
expect "password:"
send "root\r"

interact
```

It seems to works till the first send. Then however gets stuck and waits for an input? (wrong expect?)

Comment: "But B deletes its storage on reboot", is that expected behavior?

Comment: Another option can be using ssh keys, instead of writing password into script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the part you're having trouble with:

```
spawn ssh "root@$ip mkdir -p .ssh"
expect "password:"
send "root\r"
expect "(yes/no)? "
send "yes\r"
```

After you send the password you're waiting 30 seconds for `(yes/no?` to appear, but it might not appear if you've connected to that machine before. You want to *conditionally* expect that y/n prompt:

```
spawn ssh "root@$ip mkdir -p .ssh"
expect {
    "(yes/no)? " { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
    "password:"  { send "root\r" }
}
expect eof
```

That form of the expect command allows you to look for multiple strings simultaneously. If the first one seen is "(yes/no)? ", then send "yes" and continue with this expect command. When you see "password:", send the password and let the expect command end.

You might want to change the second spawn command 
so a shell can handle the pipeline.

```
set cmd [format {cat "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "root@%s" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'} $ip]
spawn sh -c $cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` dose not handle input redirection the way you want it to.
The easiest solution is to create a separate shell script that will do the copying and let `expect` only handle the password prompt.

This is what works for me:

`cat copykey.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@host "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

`cat copykey.expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 30

spawn ssh user@host mkdir -p .ssh
expect "password:"
send "password\n"
expect "$ "

spawn ~/copykey.sh 
expect "password:"
send "password\n"
expect "$ "
```

Comment: used your script ->spawn id exp6 not opened

Comment: make sure `~/.ssh` dose not exist on the remote side.

Comment: @TheCheatsrichter: did this solve your problem? If not, what was the fix, if you found one?

Answer (score 0):

Need to give ip,username,password as command line argument(Remotelogin.exp)

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set ip [lindex $argv 0]
    set user [lindex $argv 1]
    set password [lindex $argv 2]
    spawn ssh $user@$ip
    expect {
    "(yes/no)?" {

                  send "yes\r"

                  expect "password:"

                  send "$password\r"

                }

    "password:" {
                   send "$password\r"
                }
           }
```

`

Example: ./Remotelogin.exp